# Configurar parámetro URL **$routeParams**

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, configuración

Buenas tardes. Estoy con un proyecto donde uso **Angularjs** y en uno de los apartados del proyecto tengo que configurar el parámetro Url y debo mostrar el valor del parámetro en **Template**.
Es una sección que se llama **instrucciones** y cuando pincho en ella me aparece un template mostrandome este mensaje: instrucciones.
¿Cómo puedo hacer lo de la configuración del **parámetro URl**?

Os dejo aquí el código del apartado **instrucciones**

**HTML:**

```
<h1> Instrucciones  </h1>
<div marked src="'/scripts/docs/Introduccion.js'" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('App')
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('instrucciones', {
                url: '/instrucciones',
                controller: 'InstCtrl as inst',
                templateUrl: '/scripts/app/estados/instrucciones/instrucciones.html'
            })
        $routeParams
        $routeProvider

         });


angular.module('App').controller('InstCtrl', instCtrl);

function instCtrl($scope, $http) {

    var inst = this;
    inst.name = '//ABANCA';


};
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los $routeParams se usan en el controlador de la vista. Me explico; si quieres enviar parametros por ruta a la dirección /instrucciones, deberás declarar el estado de esta manera:

```
    .state('instrucciones', {
        url: '/instrucciones/:id',
        controller: 'InstCtrl as inst',
        templateUrl: '/scripts/app/estados/instrucciones/instrucciones.html'
    });
```

Y entonces en tu controlador debes inyectar $routeParams así:

```
angular.module('App').controller('InstCtrl', instCtrl);
function instCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
   var inst = this;
   if ($routeParams.id) {
     inst.name = $routeParams.id;
   }
};
```

Comment: Y si deseo pasar por la url dos parámetros como sería?
Saludos.